# How do EU countries negotiate (and divide among themselves) fishing quotas outside of EU waters?

Tags: european-union, fishing

Let's say the Netherlands wants to fish in the [EEZ of Sierra Leone](http://www.marineregions.org/gazetteer.php?p=details&id=8390). Is the EU as body involved in this at all? Or does the Netherlands negotiate fishing rights with the non-EU country in question, possibly through an [RFMO](https://ec.europa.eu/fisheries/cfp/international/rfmo_en)? If the EU does get involved, does it divvy up whatever is negotiated with the non-EU country among (several) EU member states, according to some predetermined method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the responsibilities of the EU Commission ([source](https://ec.europa.eu/fisheries/cfp/international/agreements_en)):

> [EU Sustainable Fisheries Partnership Agreements](https://publications.europa.eu/en/publication-detail/-/publication/c8b5d962-0d38-11e7-8a35-01aa75ed71a1/language-en/format-PDF/source-37907030) ... with non-EU
>   countries are negotiated and concluded by the Commission on behalf of
>   the EU. They allow EU vessels to fish for surplus stocks in the
>   country's exclusive economic zone (EEZ), in a legally regulated
>   environment. These agreements also focus on resource conservation and
>   environmental sustainability, ensuring that all EU vessels are subject
>   to the same rules of control and transparency. At the same time, a
>   clause concerning respect for human rights has been included in all
>   protocols to fisheries agreements.

The EU has several of these agreements in place:

[image: EU Fisheries agreements]

As for the methodologies:

> There are two main types of agreements:
>
> - Tuna agreements – allow EU vessels to pursue migrating tuna stocks as they move along the shores of Africa and through the Indian Ocean.
> - Mixed agreements – provide access to a wide range of fish stocks in the partner country's exclusive economic zone.
>
> In exchange, the EU pays the partner countries a financial
>   contribution composed of 2 distinct parts:
>
> - access rights to the EEZ
> - sectorial support which aims to promote sustainable fisheries development in the partner countries, by strengthening their
>     administrative and scientific capacity through a focus on sustainable
>     fisheries management, monitoring, control and surveillance

And regarding the share by member state ([source](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/policies/eu-fish-stocks/)):

> The EU also sets annual catch limits for most commercial fish stocks.
>   These are also called **total allowable catches (TACs)** or fishing
>   opportunities. Each TAC is shared among the EU member states through
>   national quotas. Individual member states are responsible for ensuring
>   that their quotas are not overfished.
>
> **For fish stocks that are shared and jointly managed with non-EU**
>   **countries, the TACs agreed at EU level have to be in line with the**
>   **results of recurring consultations with those non-EU countries.** These
>   consultations are based on international agreements on cooperation in
>   fisheries management.